# udp listener does not collect all data

Tags: c#, udp

I wrote this c# code which is executed in a TPL which is one of the Tasks of my Backgroundworker.
It is a udp server listener that can receive a cancel signal with the "run_server" flag.
It works fines when I collect 6 events, but when I have more packets, it does not collect the rest of them.
I tried increasing the TIMEOUT but that did not work.
Note: I have used a shorter polling rate instead of using the timeout because I want to be able to cancel out within a second but want the udp timout to be 16 seconds.
I also added the sleep because the polling did no seem to pause at all.
Any ideas?

```
run_server = true;
try
{
    Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    // specify timeout to prevent the thread from freezing
    const int TIMEOUT = 16000; // millisecond
    const int CANCELATION_DELAY = 500; // millisecond
    IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
    EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)iep;
    sock.Bind(iep);
    IPEndPoint remote_ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
    EndPoint remote_ep = (EndPoint)iep;
    int iter = 0;
    try
    {
        while (run_server && (iter < (TIMEOUT / CANCELATION_DELAY)))
        {
            if (sock.Poll(CANCELATION_DELAY, SelectMode.SelectRead))
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[10240];
                int len = sock.Receive(data);
                byte[] data2 = new byte[len];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, data2, 0, len);
                Hashtable evt = (Hashtable)BsonReader.Deserialize(data2);
                trace.Add(evt);
                iter = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                iter += 1;
                Thread.Sleep(CANCELATION_DELAY);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException)
    {
    }
catch (ThreadAbortException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Closing the socket");
    sock.Close();
}
```

[UPDATE]
I changed my code to the code below.
It collects all the packets on my windows 7, but again misses some packets when I try it on a windows 2008 server regardless of the timeout value:

```
sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
// specify timeout to prevent the thread from freezing
int TIMEOUT = udp_timeout * 1000; // millisecond
const int CANCELATION_DELAY = 1000; // millisecond
IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)iep;
sock.Bind(iep);
IPEndPoint remote_ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
EndPoint remote_ep = (EndPoint)iep;
int iter = 0;

try
{
    while (run_server && (iter < (TIMEOUT / CANCELATION_DELAY)))
    {
        // socket poll uses micro-second units
        if (sock.Poll(CANCELATION_DELAY * 1000, SelectMode.SelectRead))
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024000];// make a big buffer to allow big packets come in
            int len = sock.Receive(data);
            byte[] data2 = new byte[len];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, data2, 0, len);
            try
            {
                Hashtable evt = (Hashtable)BsonReader.Deserialize(data2);
                trace.Add(evt);
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to read bson data: " + ex);
            }
            iter = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            iter += 1;
        }
    }
}
catch (SocketException)
{
    // do not worry about socket read timeout exceptions
    Console.WriteLine("socket error!");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it does not collect the rest of them? Does it hang waiting for more data? Does it leave the loop after timeout is elapsed? Who is sending these packets? Are you sure there are more than 6? Have you tried using a network sniffer to see if all packets arrive correctly before timeout elapses? By the way, have you noticed that in the Poll method, the delay is given in microseconds and not milliseconds?

Comment: I'm sure there is more data because I've implemented the same thing in python and always collect more. What happens is that it times out multiple times until "iter" value reaches (TIMEOUT / CANCELATION_DELAY) and then returns what has been collected. so it does not freeze. Also thanks for the note. I mistakenly thought that poll timeout is in milliseconds instead of microseconds. Removing the sleep command improved it so now I can collect 10 packets but still when there are more packets, I run into the same problem.

Comment: actually I tried it more times. The problem only happens the first time I collect the data. The second time, it collect all 16 packets and nothing was missing.

Comment: I think what is happening is: Your code allows a maximum of 16 packets to read and only if they arrive spaced out correctly. If the code reaches Poll function with nothing in the buffer to read, it will execute the else clause and advance the counter. Supposing two packets reach the network card while your thread sleeps, it will wake up, discover that there is data available, but only read the first packet in this iteration. If you start your read thread before any packets are sent, you are bound to miss some of the packets because you incremented your counter prematurely. Use time instead